# How to use a dynamic json in CDK to build resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

There is dynamic json file which is stored in an S3 bucket. I want to use this file to build dashboards in my CDK code. (The file contains a list of applications and pages for which I need to build CloudWatch Dashboards).

How to achieve this ?

I tried using custom resources to get the object from the S3 bucket but it is not able to resolve the value at build time. During build time I only see references to the object as `$TOKEN..`.

Comment: You need to get the object from s3 before synth

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am misunderstanding your goal, you can just use AWS SDK to make s3 call directly from your CDK code, without using custom resources. This means that CDK will fetch file at build time, not at runtime. The downside is that your build will require network access and will not be deterministic, however.

Comment: It shoud be noted that this goes against the CDK best practices.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps